# QTP - function does not work when called for authentication

Tags: function, qtp

Here's the function to be called to get username and password:

```
 Function SetWebEdit(TempObj,Value)
 Err.Clear
 On Error Resume Next

 If Value="" Then Exit Function 
 TempObj.Set Value              
 If Err.Number<>0 Then
    strName=Split(Err.Description,Chr(34))       
    If UBound(strName)=0 Then
        strMsg=strName(0)
    Else
        StrMsg=strName(1)
    End If
    strDesc=Err.Description
```

'       On Error Goto 0 'ExitTestIteration will not work, err object will be  restored
        Report ATSNo&" - "&TestCaseName&"-SetWebEdit - Run Error - "&TempObj.GetTOProperty("html id")&"- "&strDesc , "Fail", "Yes", obj_homepage
     End If
     End Function

I have the below function to be called to authenticate the sign in process:

```
Function Authenticate()

'Set the username and password and click on Sign in
 Set Global_Authentication=obj_homepage.WebElement("objectid")
'Global_Authentication.highlight
if Global_Authentication.Exist(10) then
Call SetWebEdit(Username,"name")
Encryped_Pwd="12345"
Password.SetSecure Encryped_Pwd
wait(2)
Call ClickWebButton(Signin)
wait(5)
End if
End Function
```

*it works just fine except for one specific time below:*

```
Function Check_Out()

'Set Resolve_click = obj_homepage.WebElement("objectid")
Set Resolve_click = obj_homepage.WebElement("objectid")
IF Resolve_click.Exist(10) then
Call ClickWebElement(Resolve_click)
End IF
wait(5)

Set Authorize_button = obj_homepage.WebButton("objectid")
If Authorize_button.Exist(10) Then
Call ClickWebButton(Authorize_button)

End if
    wait(10)

    Call Authenticate()

    wait(15)
    Set Paper_Form_Signed = obj_homepage.WebButton("objectid")
    If Paper_Form_Signed.Exist(10) Then
    Call ClickWebButton(Paper_Form_Signed)
    End if 
    wait(8)
End Function
```

The Authorize button gets clicked, but it does not enter the username and password. Please let me know the issue and a possible solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming all your functions and your ID's (which you have hidden from the code you have pasted above) are working fine, there doesn't seem to be any issue in code. Can you please put a breakpoint and run it in debug mode and let us know on which line exactly is the error and what error does QTP shows, without it its just a guessing game.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There is no error when running the code and the application moves to the next page when doing it manually. It doesn't go to the next page even if I give the code for username and password in the function itself. I will run in debug mode and see the result.

Comment: Do you get sign in page twice ?? Because as per your code you sign in once when Authorize button exists and then again you try to give username and password when you call Authenticate() function. (Sorry checked your code once again properly after your comment said its not giving error probably because its not able to find username and password object again when you call Authenticate(). I am not sure if this is the error but it could be, check and let me know)

Comment: Nope.. I have modified the code that I used latest. And, if the objects are not identified, then it should be the same for the previous scenario as well. But it enters the value in the text boxes in other scenarios. Only this case is not working.

Comment: Any updates on how script is running in debug mode ? in your updated code I cannot find the set for Username,Password and Signin objects. Also your Authorize_button is not getting clicked anywhere

Comment: I have added the code for setting username and password.

Comment: Nope, I haven't run the script in debug mode yet. I will update after running it.